# Using CancellationTokens in Timer callback method

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, cancellation-token

I am implementing a `Windows Service` that will perform some expensive `Database operations`, such as retrieving and storing data from some tables into others with the intention of creating summaries, crunching data for reports etc.

I am using a `Timer object` to control the time when I want the operations to occur, and it's all good about that, my main issue here is how to go about Cancellations, when someone decides to stop the `service`, or Windows reboots, anything that calls `OnStop()` Method.

My code looks like this:

**code:**

```
tmr = new Timer(new TimerCallback(tmr_Tick), cTs.Token, 0, 1000);
```

I have a `CancellationTokenSource` as a global variable named `cTs` in the service.

When the `OnStop` method is called I just set `cTs.Cancel()`

My `Callback` looks like this:

**Callback:**

```
    private void tmr_Tick(object sender)
    {
        if (((CancellationToken)sender).IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            tmr.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            return;
        }

        if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Equals(intervalRepetition))
            Task.Run(async () => { await ProcessData((CancellationToken)sender); });
    }
```

My question is about the `TimerCallback`, since I didn't find anything that helps dealing with Tokens in it, I am passing the token as a `State object`, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, so I am looking for advice.

Also what should I do when `IsCancellationRequested` is set? Should I implement a better exit strategy, perhaps throwing a cancellation exception?

Is the propagation of the Token down to that `ProcessData` Method correct? if I return from above it, the `ProcessData` Method will answer to the Token? I figured it would, but I am not entirely sure, since its async and all that.

Comment: Instead of using `IsCancellationRequested` you can surround your code in a try / catch clause and then catch the exception `OperationCanceledException`

Comment: you saying that if a cancellation is requested out of scope, it will throw an exception in that method at that moment?

Comment: The CancellationToken will bubble up the cancelation to all scopes who have access to it.

Comment: Thank you @Dilip for the edit, some times people come and edit my questions removind some formatted words saying they are common words and some people come and edit it saying its code, so i never really know when to put words as code hahahaha

Comment: @silkfire if i don't ask if the cancellation was requested i will never be able to stop my code. that goes out of the way Cancellation works.

Comment: Yes you will. You stop your execution in the `catch` clause.

Comment: it wont bubble up throw Exception and it's not a linear operation, it don't just goes up, it does parallel too.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how the `CancellationToken` actually works :)

Comment: At least it's how they implemented it in some examples :-)

Comment: if  you get a cancellation by an external token, you have to ask it, otherwise you wont have anyway to know.

Comment: You not only need to cancel currently running work, but you also need to wait for that work to finish, so just cancellation is not enough for graceful shutdown.

Comment: What you propose i do then @Evk?

Comment: you saying i need some way to let the OnStop Method know i have some "stuff" happening and it should wait until i say it's safe to finish?

Comment: LIke a ManualResetEvent ?

Comment: It depends on situation. For example, are you ok that `ProcessData` might be interrupted right in the middle? If you don't wait for completion of all running tasks - they all will be killed when you return from `OnStop` (if they are running on background threads, which is the case with `Task.Run`). Sometimes that might be ok, if `ProcessData` is atomic (either does everything or nothing), for example inserts some stuff into database in single transaction. But most often that is not ok. In that case you need some list of active tasks and a means to wait for them to complete.

Comment: Well i am sending a token down into it :-\ it does quite a big amount of operations in there.

Comment: i am thinking about call cTs.Token instead of using the sender argument, tho.

Comment: You are sending a token, but in OnStop you just do `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`. This call is not blocking and will return immediately. After that, you will return from OnStop and all tasks will be killed, without waiting for tasks to actually react to that cancellation.

Comment: You are right, i need to block it somehow, an awaiter of some sort. :-\

Comment: Is there a way to signal that from within the token?

Comment: What if i use a Thread Pool and wait on that pool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161815/discussion-between-zorkind-and-evk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not only to request cancellation of current active work, but actually wait for all active tasks to react to that cancellation and complete. In your current approach you do this:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
public override void OnStop() {
    _cts.Cancel();
}
```

This won't help anything, because as soon as cancellation is requested, you will return from OnStop method and all background threads (on which your work is performed because of `Task.Run`) will be killed without waiting for them to finish.

So you need some way to wait for them to finish before returning from `OnStop`. One way to do that is use `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse`, like this:

```
private readonly object _activeTasksLock = new object();
private int _activeTasks;
private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async Task ProcessData(CancellationToken ct) {
    lock (_activeTasksLock) {
        // increment number of active tasks
        _activeTasks++;
    }
    try {
        // do stuff
        await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
        // check cancellation token and exit if necessary
    }
    finally {
        lock (_activeTasksLock) {
            // decrement and notify
            _activeTasks--;
            Monitor.Pulse(_activeTasksLock);
        }
    }
}

public override void OnStop() {
    // dispose\stop your timer here
    // then cancel
    _cts.Cancel();
    // then wait until all is done
    lock (_activeTasksLock) {
        while (_activeTasks > 0)
            Monitor.Wait(_activeTasksLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please make that async? :-)

Comment: @Zorkind sure, I've changed `ProcessData` to be async (doesn't change anything really).

Comment: Can't i do that using the ThreadPool instead? it looks like a lot of code to give that control and the ProcessData is not the only method i call, i have a bunch of other deeper async calls i make.

Comment: You need to do that only in the main method which you start from timer, not in all async calls that are called from this main method (`ProcessData` in this case).

Comment: Right, makes sense.

Comment: what you think of the ManualResetEvent for this? i think it takes a lot less code to use, doing a WaitOne() and then if the Cancellation is requested i just do a Set() at the end of my method.

Comment: @Zorkind but you have several tasks running. As soon as first will set that event - your waiter will unblock and exit, killing all other tasks. If use ManualResetEvent - you need to have a list of them (one for each task), and that will result in more code. I also don't see a lot of code here. One increment at start, one decrement at the end - that's all.

Comment: What about System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment instead of locking? hahaha sorry i am just trying to improve it :-)

Comment: You can increment and decrement with that, but how would you wait until it reaches 0? Well you can of course do something like `while (_activeTasks > 0) Thread.Sleep(100)` but I cannot say I like that (but if you would do that - mark `_activeTasks` with `volatile` keyword or you might get quite unexpected results.

Comment: Right :-) i guess i am micro optimizing here, it's a flaw i have, i tend to try and simplify stuff :-)